# Display only one column in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a list, which is need to be shown as data. But [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) with accepts data as `Object[][]`, but will give `Object[]`.

How do I display only one column in a table?

Comment: If you have a list which needs to be shown, why not use a `JList`. An a `JTable` accept any kind of `TableModel`, also one with one column

Comment: @Damodar if is possible, then don't use JList, JList is broken JTable, missing a few very important methods in comparing with JTable :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps try the following...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
model.addColumn("MyColumnHeader",dataArray);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson good catch. He probably refers to the `addColumn` method on `DefaultTableModel` which accepts the same parameters

Comment: @Robin When someone posts an SSCCE as an answer, I might glance at the code,  compile/run it if I'm interested to investigate further..  But when answers are code snippets I give them closer attention.

Comment: Ah apologies, yes I was referring to addColumn() - this is now corrected.